# ruby/RoR reading from serialport all the time as well as from interface

Tags: ruby, multithreading, arduino

I'm trying to set up a web application using RoR to be able to control my Arduino using the web interface. Probably my approach is what is wrong here, because i'm having hard time reading what arduino is saying on the serial while sending commands. My main and future objective would be listing (streaming) the serial port to my web interface, and on the server side to react if some specific commands are given on the serial port.

What have i tryed already? I though using Threads would be a good idea, but im having some issues. First of all i tried the easiest away, by creating a new Thred and using .join. Since the serial.gets was on a while true with no way of getting out it, my server was hanging there for ever.

Even tho that not beeing what i want to have at the end, i try to limit my while true putting a way out ( as seen on the code ) by running it 10 times.

My arduino code (it works):

```
char receivedChar;
boolean newData = false;

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
 Serial.println("<Arduino is ready>");
}

void loop() {
 recvOneChar();
}

void recvOneChar() {
 if (Serial.available() > 0) {
  receivedChar = Serial.read();
  if (receivedChar == '1') {
   digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
   Serial.println("LED IS ON");
  }else if (receivedChar == '2' ){
   digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
   Serial.println("LED IS OFF");
  }
 }
}
```

Controller on RoR:

```
def blink_led
  puts "blink_led action called"
  t1 = Thread.new do
    Setting.blink_led
  end
  Setting.read_board
  t1.join
end
```

Model on RoR:

```
@port_str = "/dev/tty.usbmodem14201"
@baud_rate = 9600
@data_bits = 8
@stop_bits = 1
@parity = SerialPort::NONE


def self.read_board
    puts "INSIDE READ METHOD"
    sp = SerialPort.new(@port_str, @baud_rate, @data_bits, @stop_bits, @parity)

    i = 0
    while i < 10 do
      message = sp.gets
      if message
        message.chomp!

        puts message
      end
      i += 1
    end
end

def self.blink_led
    puts "INSIDE BLINK METHOD"
    sp = SerialPort.new(@port_str, @baud_rate, @data_bits, @stop_bits, @parity)

    #just read forever
    i = 0
    while i < 5
        sp.write('1');
        sleep(1)
        sp.write('2');
        sleep(1)
        i += 1
    end

    sp.close
end
```

with my naive experience i expected to perfectly get once i call the controller method using a button, to see the LED blinking ( it blinks) and at the same time to it to see on my server the PUTS saying LED IS ON/OFF. (expecting everything to run perfectly)
Well that didn't quite happen, and i got some weird results:

before adding the i counter on my while my server runs 1 time ok-ish ( the first time i pressed the button), and after that is just weird.
first run:

```
blink_led action called
INSIDE READ METHOD
INSIDE BLINK METHOD
Completed 200 OK in 6015ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

IS D ISIS OLS ONLED IS OFF
LED IS ON
LED IS OFF
LED IS ON
LED IS OFF
```

it just hangs there.

Now with the get counter on the while loop, it really does not do what i want, i want this to be running all the time ( is case something happens) i'm also sending data to the serial from another source ( a small ruby script) and want my server to be able to check/react to it.

```
blink_led action called
INSIDE READ METHOD
INSIDE BLINK METHOD
LED IS LED IS OFF
Completed 200 OK in 6013ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

LED IS ON
LED IS OFF
LED IS ON
LED IS OFF
LED IS ON
LED IS OFF
LED IS ON
LED IS OFF
```

the messages at least showed correctly, but my server still hangs.

Is my approached here all wrong? what would be the best way to achieve what I want to achieve? At the end I want my server to be able to run the serial read command all the time, while reacting to what is read from the serial port and reacting to the inputs on the interface, like a push of a button. Once this is accomplished, i wanna to be able to "stream" (don't know if that is the right word for it) my serial port to the interface.

EDIT1 : corrected some typos, and learned how to kill the server process every time it hangs

Edit2: To make my question clear. I'm looking to build a 2 way communication, 1 way from the interface/server to the arduino and from the arduino to my server. I'm looking to build something where i can send commands to the arduino and read the answers from it. So far i have a action/method that sends the command to blink to the arduino, sending "1" or "2", to which arduino "LED is on" "LED is off" accordingly responds. But this (so far) is only doable when my server knows it will get an answer.

I have a small ruby script that sends the same commands to turn the LED on and off and what i'm missing is my server to be able to notice that something was written on the Serialport (on this case, the response from arduino saying "LED is on"/"LED is off") when this event was from another source triggered .

Comment: Apologies if I am missing something, but if `Setting.blink_led` thread loops forever, and you call `.join` on that thread in the controller, then the controller will hang forever.

Comment: Oh, ignore the comment there, it was from a tutorial code I was trying out. The Setting.blink_led just blinks the led. I would love to know, what would be the best approach to have a always running method (at least on one view) that read the serial, and do different actions accordingly.

Comment: I'm not what you mean by an "always running method". If you are gettings commands from the front end, can't you have methods that fire single read/write operations to the Arduino? Because I mean, you _can_ make a background thread which is "always runinng", but I'm not entirely clear what you would need that for. Is it because you need to keep the connection to the Serial Port open? In which case you could change the `sp` variable to a constant

Comment: updated my question to answer you, check my second edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `read_board` method to a neverending background thread. It can call some other method when it receives a message, and updates the front end using websockets / action cable.

```
  # app/models/setting.rb

  def self.read_board
    sp = SerialPort.new(@port_str, @baud_rate, @data_bits, @stop_bits, @parity)
    Thread.new do

      loop do
        message = sp.gets # This will probably wait for input
        if message
          message.chomp!
          message_received(message)
        end
      end

    end
  end

  def self.message_received(message)
    # Alert clients of message using websockets / actioncable.
  end
```

Call this method from somewhere (it needs to be called once only)

```
# config/initializers/read_board.rb

Setting.read_board
```

You'd need to fill in the `message_received` method. If you don't want to mess with action cable / websockets, you could make a array which stores the new messages, and send a query on a loop from the front end which pops from the list. However, using websockets is a better choice. Unfortunately, it's a bit too complex to explain the setup in this answer, but if you search around you will find good tutorials.

I would say try and make a demo project for websockets / actioncable (just a simple chat room, there are tons of tutorials for this), then afterwards try and adapt the code for the arduino project

Comment: Thx for the answer, I will try it out tomorrow evening.